# How to fix this error : The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

[The error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bCk5.jpg)

[The index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2oTE.jpg)

I'm trying to Edit an Index in my MVC .net application. It was working perfectly before I changed for a different View in Mysql Server.

I tried to update the model.edmx for the new View which I thought would have worked but it cannot stop showing me this error while trying to edit. I think this is a mapping issue but I cannot find the problem

controller :

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Graduated_Students graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Find(id);
        if (graduates == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(graduates);
    }
```

Model :

```
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CohortId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ContractStatus { get; set; }
    public string DepositStatus { get; set; }
    public string GraduationStatus { get; set; }
}
```

View :

```
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(Resource.Profile, "Details", new { id = item.ID })
                        @Html.ActionLink(Resource.Edit, "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
                        @Html.ActionLink(Resource.Delete, "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database View does not have a primary key. Find() searches for a primary key, so can not be used to search a View.  Change it to FirstOrDefault():

```
Graduated_Students graduates = db.Graduated_Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly, I did not know that find() couldnt be use with a view... !

Comment: @MartinChantal Happy to help. If you're all set, please mark as answered.